# É possivel exibir um form através de um MessageDialog?

Tags: delphi

Com o `MessageDialog`, gostaria de criar componentes (botões) em tempo de execução e definir o tamanho e o texto dos botões dessa `MessageDialog`.

Além disso, preciso exibir alguns *forms* de acordo com o botão que for escolhido nessa `MessageDialog`.

É possível?

Comment: Você pode explicar e contextualizar melhor? O texto da pergunta está bastante confuso e esta questão já está com 3 votos para fechar como "*não está clara o suficiente*" e "*ampla demais*". E nenhum destes votos de fechamento é meu.

Comment: Acho que ficou bem claro, já que o amigo ali embaixo atendeu perfeitamente o que eu queria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível, segue exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: Integer;
 f: Tform;
 clicado : Integer;
begin
  f:= createmessagedialog('Deseja Abrir outro Formulário?',
   mtconfirmation,[mbyes,mbno,mbok,mbcancel]);

    try
      for i:=0 to f.componentCount -1 do
       if f.components[i] is tbutton then
        with tbutton(f.components[i]) do
         case modalresult of
           mryes   : caption := '&Sim';
           mrno    : caption := '&Não';
           mrok    : caption := '&Certo';
           mrcancel: caption := '&Errado';
         end;
        f.caption := 'Opções'; //Caption da Janelinha

        //Aqui passamos o Código de qual o botão clicado
        clicado := f.showmodal;
       finally
        f.free;
       end;

    if clicado = 6 then
    begin
      //Aqui você chama o formulário
    end;

end;
```

Nome dos botões disponíveis e seus respectivos Códigos:

mrNone = 0;
mrOk = 1;
mrCancel = 2;
mrAbort = 3;
mrRetry = 4;
mrIgnore = 5;
mrYes = 6;
mrNo = 7;
mrClose = 8;
mrAll = 12;
mrNoToAll = 13;
mrYesToAll = 14;

Comment: Seria possível aumentar o tamanho dos botões?

Comment: O tamanho deles é default da VCL, da pra aumentar mas o nível para isso ja outro assunto! O que você pode fazer é criar uma janelinha personalizada, e dar ShowModal nela, ficando assim como se fosse uma MessageBox, ai sim você pode colocar os botões do tamanho que quiser dentre outras personalizações!